# Google maps. Coordinate parser by titles

Tags: google-maps, maps

I think it's common task.
I have about 2400 raws in database with titles of skiing resorts. I have to parse coordimate of point in search results of each raw. Sometimes, result has more than one point, how can i occurate results?
Suggest best algorytm for this task. May be [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) has some helpfull methods for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can consider about JQuery to send a async request to the the server, the server responses for retrieving the data. After retrieving your rows of data, you can build these position with JSON which likes this [{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:2}]; it means two rows of data. When the server method runs completely, the client side raises a callback which can access result JSON; the JSON can be manually parsed by you to the LatLng object in Google API right. I think you know the rest stuffs.

Hope it helps.